# F# dll in F# script

Tags: c#, dll, f#

I have a C# dll that I need to reference in F#. I can do this fine in a .fs file, but I can't seem to get it to work in an F# script (.fsx) It is strange because in my script, I have no problem referencing F# dlls. I thought C# dlls and F# dlls were essentially the same.

EDIT:

I have two dlls (1) csharp.dll and (2) fsharp.dll built with csharp and fsharp respectively. I reference them with:

```
#r "bin\Debug\csharp.dll"
#r "bin\Debug\fsharp.dll"
```

which the compiler recognizes. The line where this occurs looks like this:

```
let new_object = new fsharp.type(Observable<csharp.type>)
```

Where I'm creating an object defined in fsharp.dll which takes an observer of a type defined in csharp.dll. When I try to run it in FSharp interactive, I get the following error:

error FS0074: The type referenced through 'csharp.type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'csharp'.

The thing that doesn't make sense is that csharp.type had been used successfully in a previous line. But when we introduce the csharp.type with an fsharp.type, I get an error all of a sudden saying the csharp type is missing an assembly reference, even though the problem seems to be with the fsharp.type.

Comment: Could you add a sample of script you are using and the error? Are you using `#r` directive to refer C# dll from the script?

Comment: What if you refer the full path of csharp.dll in the script. Will it give you the same error?

Comment: If I refer the full path of the csharp.dll, it actually tells me that the path doesn't exist, so I have to do it this way.

Comment: Where (in which dll)  the type `Observable<T>` is defined?

Comment: note that the paths are .NET strings and you might have hit an escape sequence somewhere, so better use something like `#r @"bin\Debug\csharp.dll"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll need also refer in the script `System.Reactive.dll` or wherever the class `Observable<T>` is defined

Answer (score 1):

@Petr is correct. You need to add all references, and their references.

If you are using Visual Studio, I suggest that you install Visual F# Power Tools. When installed, right-click 'References' under your project and choose to 'Generate references for F# interactive'.

This will generate (and keep updated!) the files

- {ProjRoot}/Scripts/load-references.fsx
- {ProjRoot}/Scripts/load-project.fsx

So in your F# script (assuming it is in the project root), you just do

```
#load "Scripts/load-project.fsx"
```

These generated files should go into your version control of choice.